# Ruby on Rails: ActiveRecord with list of data (like has_many for pieces of data, not objects)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, list, activerecord, has-many

If I want to have a record in Rails that has many options, such as a selection of times, then what is the best method for storing this in the record?  I don't really want to setup the times as objects and use has_many, since 12:17pm doesn't really make sense as an object.  What do I use to put a list of variable size into an ActiveRecord?

As an example, consider a DB of videos in a video collection.  And for each video we want a list of all the dates that it was watched.  We also have no need to search dates across all the videos, we just want to be able to list and maybe edit the dates for a given video object.

Comment: What is the use of these times / items? are they just displayed. Are you going to need to search them? something else?    what database are you using? (also the time standalone might not make sense as an object, but is there other data that is tied to the time)

Comment: Thanks for the question - I'll update the original post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why it seem unaesthetic to have the Times as their own database table but it might be the easiest option.

Database tables often get created which aren't pretty - join tables, for examples. Perhaps the model could be called `TimeOption` and it would have a foreign key. Seems like you already understand how to do, this though.

I'm also assuming the options are dynamic, otherwise they can just be stored in an application constant.

Another option is to use Postgres' array data type, which is new but I haven't used.

Another option is to serialize the array of Times into `json`, `yaml`, or `csv` and then store the serialized string in the database. Deserialize the data to read it and reserialize to save.

Comment: I'm using sqlite3, but I suppose I could migrate to and learn Postgres, but it seems that this should be simple with sqlite3 or MySQL.  It has the ability to track has_many, so it must have some mechanism for storing lists.

Though actually serializing the array makes quite a bit of sense if the data is fairly regular (such as times) - I think that might be the easiest solution, though disappointing if it's the only reasonable solution.

Comment: In your example I would contend you might want to store data about the viewing.  Movie has_many viewings, and that viewing contains date/time, who viewed it, etc.. but if not then Either serialization or an array datatype is what I would look at (Which is why I asked what DB you where using)